# How to prove that $X \subseteq Y \oplus (Z \cap X)$ if $Y \subseteq X$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum

> I need to prove that $X \subseteq Y \oplus (Z \cap X)$ if $Y \subseteq X$ and $V=Y \oplus Z$ and $X,Y,Z$ are subspaces of $V$.

We could say that because $V=Y \oplus Z$ then for $x \in X$, $y \in Y$ and $z \in Z$ we have $x=y+z$. But $Z=(Z \cap X) \cup Q$ where $Q \cap X=\{0\}$. Then I'm tempted to say that because of that $X \subseteq Y\oplus (Z \cap X)$ but I feel I haven't really proved this.

Howe can I prove this?

Comment: Before answering I like to point out that the question in the title is quite different from that in the text. The difference is, of course, the 'if $Y \subset X$' in the title, that doesn't come back in the text.

Comment: Why, I did mention both in the text and in the headline that $Y \subseteq X$. Unless you meant something else

Comment: O right, I just overlooked it. Sorry.

Comment: It appears that you haven't used the fact that $Y\subset X$, which is somewhat important.

Comment: Someting else: the sentence 'for $x \in X, y \in Y, z \in Z$ we have $x = y + z$' is wrong when taken literally as stated. The correct version is: for $x \in X$ there exist unique $y \in Y$ and $z \in Z$ such that $x = y + z$. It is important to realize that once $x$ is chosen, $y$ and $z$ satisfying your equation are completely determined. There is no room left to freely choose them as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every element of $V$ can be uniquely written in the form $y + z$, where $y \in Y$ and $z \in Z.$

You need to show that for $x \in X$, the element $z$ in this decomposition $x = y + z$ comes from $Z \cap X$. But this is because $$z = x-y \in X,$$ since we assumed $Y \subseteq X.$